# C++ Pointers -- Weird Loop Behavior

Tags: c++, pointers

From main, I am trying to call a prime function in mymath.cpp -- it has some 
very strange behaviour that I do not understand. (Note, the algorithm doesn't work 
yet -- but that's not what is strange to me.)

The strange thing is, if I comment out the line:

```
cout << "n:" << lastPrime->pnum <<"\n";
```

... in mymath.cpp, my loop in main only runs twice. If I leave it in, my loop in main runs all the way up to i = 50;

MAIN.CPP

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include "stat.h"
#include "mymath.h";

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    for (int i = 3; i<= 50; i++)
    {
        if (isPrime(i))
        {
            cout << i << " is prime!\n";
        }
        else
        {
            cout << i << " is NOT prime\n";
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

MYMATH.CPP

```
#include "mymath.h"
#include <math.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

prime two;
prime * lastPrime = &two;
prime * firstPrime = &two;

bool isPrime(long long n)
{
  two.pnum=2;
  prime * currentPrime = &two;

  if ( n < 2)
      return false;

  long long squareRoot = sqrt(n);

  while(true)
  {
      if (n % currentPrime->pnum==0)
      {
          //n is divisible by a prime number, nothing left to do.
          return false;
      }
      else
      {
          //n is not divisible by a prime... check next one
          {
          if (currentPrime->pprime == 0 || currentPrime->pnum > squareRoot)
              {
                  //this is prime
                  prime addPrime;
                  addPrime.pnum=n;
                  addPrime.pprime=0;
                  lastPrime->pprime=&addPrime;
                  lastPrime=&addPrime;
                  cout << "n:" << lastPrime->pnum <<"\n";
                  return true;
              }
              else
              {
                  //may not be prime, check next
                  currentPrime = currentPrime->pprime;
              }
          }
      }
  }
  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code has [undefined behaviour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) as a local variable, named `addPrime`, is being used beyond its lifetime:

```
    lastPrime->pprime=&addPrime;
    lastPrime=&addPrime;
    cout << "n:" << lastPrime->pnum <<"\n";
    return true;
} // 'lastPrime' is now a dangling pointer because it holds the address
  // of 'addPrime' whose lifetime has ended.
```

To correct, you need to dynamically allocate a `prime` using `new` instead. **But**, it appears (without the definition of `prime` I am uncertain) the code is building a list of `prime`s encountered. Suggest using a [`std::vector<prime>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) to build the list and let it manage memory for you.

If a `std::vector<prime>` is not an option, for whatever reason, then ensure all instances of `prime` are dynamically allocated and not a mix of dynamically allocated instances and non-dynamically allocated instances (such as the global `two`) as it is illegal to `delete` an object not dynamically allocated.

Comment: Thanks -- I kind of understand.  Dynamically allocated means the memory will not be rewritten until I free it.  Locally non-dynamically allocated means my memory may be rewritten EVEN if I have a pointer to it?

Answer (score 2):

Problems that come and go as you add or remove innocuous code almost always are the result of a bad pointer; sometimes it overwrites something that's important and sometimes it overwrites something that doesn't matter.

In this case, the bad pointer comes from taking the address of `addPrime` and saving it. At the end of the block `addPrime` goes away, and the pointer to it becomes invalid.